# Does FL based consulting LLC have to pay NY state income tax?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, limited-liability-company, new-york, florida

An LLC is registered and based in Florida.  It conducts consultations in FL for New York-based companies, wherein an employee of the NY company travels to FL for the consultation.  At no point does an employee of the FL LLC travel to NY to consult.

Does the FL company have to pay NY state income tax on the consultation fee it receives from the NY company?

Comment: Does the LLC consultant have any ties with New York? Is the LLC taxed as Corporation or Partnership? If partnership - do any of the partners have anything to do with New York? Sorry for so many questions, my crystal ball is not working right now.

Comment: No ties to NY other than being former residents.  LLC taxed as a partnership, nothing to do with NY, other than being former residents in NY.

Comment: Well, then, you have the "leave me alone" problem with the NYS. I suggest you ask a licensed professional.

Comment: @littleadv, what is the "leave me alone" problem?

Comment: @briantist NYS is notorious for not letting former residents go off the hook that easily.